# ERROR New missing/unsatisfied dependencies: (Cannot configure datasource)

Tags: jpa, jboss, jboss7.x

I have a web app using JSF(Primefaces), JPA(Hibernate) and EJBs and have trouble to configure the data source on JBoss . I am getting the following error:

```
2012/10/31 07:20:17,948 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.deployers.jdbc] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)

2012/10/31 07:20:18,836 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS015870: Deploy of deployment "ROOT.war" was rolled back with failure message {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#test\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MysqlDSMissing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#test\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MysqlDS]"]}

2012/10/31 07:20:19,252 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS015877: Stopped deployment ROOT.war in 413ms

2012/10/31 07:20:19,255 INFO  [org.jboss.as.controller] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 2) JBAS014774: Service status report

JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:

      service jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MysqlDS (missing) dependents: [service jboss.persistenceunit."ROOT.war#test"]

2012/10/31 07:20:19,334 ERROR [org.jboss.as.server.deployment.scanner] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) {"JBAS014653: Composite operation failed and was rolled back. Steps that failed:" => {"Operation step-2" => {"JBAS014771: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => ["jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#test\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MysqlDSMissing[jboss.persistenceunit.\"ROOT.war#test\"jboss.naming.context.java.jboss.datasources.MysqlDS]"]}}}
```

Below you can see my `persistence.xml`, `stanadlone.xml` and `pom.xml`.  **Am I missing some dependency in the pom.xml?**

Persistence.xml

```
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider> 

<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS</jta-data-source> 

<properties>

  <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>    

  <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>

  <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="3"/>

  <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />

</properties>
```

Standalone.xml

```
<datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true" pool-name="H2DS">
                <connection-url>jdbc:h2:${jboss.server.data.dir}/test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                <driver>h2</driver>
            <security>
                    <user-name>sa</user-name>
                    <password>sa</password>
                </security>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS" enabled="${mysql.enabled}" use-java-context="true" pool-name="MysqlDS">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://127.5.54.1:3306/researchprojects</connection-url>
                <driver>mysql</driver>
                <security>
                  <user-name>admin</user-name>
                  <password>*******</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                  <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/PostgreSQLDS" enabled="${postgresql.enabled}" use-java-context="true" pool-name="PostgreSQLDS" use-ccm="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://${env.OPENSHIFT_DB_HOST}:${env.OPENSHIFT_DB_PORT}/${env.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}</connection-url>
                <driver>postgresql</driver>
                <security>
                  <user-name>${env.OPENSHIFT_DB_USERNAME}</user-name>
                  <password>${env.OPENSHIFT_DB_PASSWORD}</password>
                </security>
                <validation>
                  <check-valid-connection-sql>SELECT 1</check-valid-connection-sql>
                </validation>
            </datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql.jdbc">
                    <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
                <driver name="postgresql" module="org.postgresql.jdbc">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

Pom.xml

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>openshifttest</groupId>
  <artifactId>openshifttest</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <name>openshifttest</name>

 <repositories>
  <repository>
        <id>scala</id>
        <name>Scala Tools</name>
        <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/</url>
        <releases>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
  <repository>  
    <id>prime-repo</id>  
    <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
    <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
    <layout>default</layout>  
    </repository>
</repositories>   

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>scala</id>
            <name>Scala Tools</name>
            <url>http://scala-tools.org/repo-releases/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
      <artifactId>jboss-javaee-6.0</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>  
        <version>3.4.1</version>  
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <profiles>
    <profile>
     <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when invoking mvn. -->
     <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app will need. -->
     <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' folder. -->
     <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
     <id>openshift</id>
     <build>
        <finalName>openshifttest</finalName>
        <plugins>
          <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
              <warName>ROOT</warName>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
                <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>

                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>compile</id>
                        <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>compile</phase>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <id>test-compile</id>
                        <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    </execution>

                    <execution>
                        <phase>process-resources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
      </build>
    </profile>
  </profiles>
</project>
```

**Could someone tell me what am I doing wrong ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

did you enable mysql datasource? as by default it is disabled.

part of configuration

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MysqlDS" enabled="${mysql.enabled}" use-java-context="true" pool-name="MysqlDS">
```

has flag ${mysql.enabled} that is system property that enables the data source in case it is mysql is enabled.

take a look at the guide http://jaitechwriteups.blogspot.com/2011/08/deploy-java-ee-application-on-openshift.html

and search for "Using the MySQL database available in OpenShift Express" chapter

that shows you what part of configuration you are missing.

Comment: where should I paste this part?

Answer (score 3):

Bit late, but after getting this error and checking loads of things, it turned out I'd simply left the definition of the driver in standalone.xml

`<drivers>
                    <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                        <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                </drivers>`

So, steps to check are:

1. add jar file mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar to jboss-eap-6.1/modules/com/mysql/main
2. add module.xml file to jboss-eap-6.1/modules/com/mysql/main

`

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql"><resources>
<resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.13-bin.jar"/>
</resources>
<dependencies>
<module name="javax.api"/>
<module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
<module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
</dependencies>
</module>
```

`

3.add this to standalone.xml
`

```
       <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS"
          pool-name="MySqlDS" enabled="true"
          use-java-context="true" jta="true" use-ccm="true">
            <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testDB</connection-url>
            <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
            <driver>mysql</driver>

            <security>
                <user-name>root</user-name>
                <password></password>
            </security>
       </datasource>
        <drivers>
            <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql">
                <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
            </driver>
        </drivers>
```

`4.  in your web app persistance.xml, add this line`

java:jboss/datasources/MySqlDS

`

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 1):

You need to install properly JDBC driver as a JBoss 7 module.

a. Create folder JBOSS_HOME\modules\com\mysql\main (yes, main subfolder has to be there)

b. copy JDBC driver to that folder

c. Create in that folder module.xml file with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="com.mysql">
  <resources>
    <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
    <module name="javax.api"/>
    <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>
</module>
```

where `mysql-connector-java-5.1.6-bin.jar` has to be replace by your driver name. Please note that for such module configuration you need to change your `module` name in driver definition to `com.mysql` (which is sort of name convention) or simply rename module name in module.xml.

After restarting server you should see in JBOSS_HOME\modules\com\mysql\main a new file .index.

I've tested that on JBoss 7.1.1.Final

Comment: I did as you said but the error insists. In fact I m trying to deploy it on openshift cloud platform that uses JBoss. When I deploy it on my local JBoss it works fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you are specifying the data source as a resource reference in web.xml, then match the name *exactly* with that in standalone.xml (or domain.xml):

**web.xml**:

```
 <resource-ref>
  <res-ref-name>java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS</res-ref-name>
  <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
  <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
 </resource-ref>
```

**standalone.xml**:

```
<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/OracleDS" pool-name="OracleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="false">
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case had a spelling issue in persistence.xml

```
<jta-data-source>java:jboss/datasources/mydb</jta-data-source>
```

has to match:

```
<datasource jta="true" jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/mydb" pool-name="EmployeeDb" enabled="true" use-ccm="false">
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. After several hours I found the solution in:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS7/How+do+I+migrate+my+application+from+AS5+or+AS6+to+AS7

> Make sure you do NOT have a space at the beginning of module.xml file
>   or you will get a "New missing/unsatisfied dependencies" error for
>   this driver.

Doh!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider trying to set up different version of mysql driver.

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.17-bin worked fine for me.
```

I hope you find this useful,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you are OK with your datasources configs. 
Make sure you installed jboss development kit to eclipse from eclipse market. 
It will work.